# Problem setting value of wx.TextCtrl in wxPython

Tags: oop, wxpython, setvalue

I'm trying to pass the directory the user chooses back to the `wx.TextCtrl` named `ChooseRoot`. This has not worked so far.

What am I doing wrong? I tried different things, but either it hangs or I get this error message.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:\Indexinator3000_x64.pyw", line 78, in OnChooseRoot
>       self.ChooseRoot.SetValue("Hello")
>   AttributeError: 'MainPanel' object has no attribute 'ChooseRoot'

```
import wx 

ID_EXIT = 110

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.parent = parent

        #------------- Setting up the buttons
        self.Run = wx.Button(self, label="Run")
        self.Run.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun )
        self.ExitB = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.ExitB.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        #------------- Setting up Static text
        self.labelChooseRoot = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Root catalog: ") 
        self.labelScratchWrk = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Sratch workspace: ")
        self.labelMergeFile = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Merge file: ")

        #------------ Setting up inputtext
        self.ChooseRoot = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(210,-1))
        self.ChooseRoot.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnChooseRoot)
        self.ScratchWrk = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(210,-1))
        self.MergeFile = wx.TextCtrl(self, -1, size=(210,-1))


        #------------- Setting up the outputbox
        self.Output = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE|wx.TE_READONLY)

        #------------- Setting up the sizer
        SizerF = wx.FlexGridSizer(3,2,5,5)
        SizerF.Add(labelChooseRoot)      #row 1, col 1
        SizerF.Add(ChooseRoot)           #row 1, col 2
        SizerF.Add(labelScratchWrk)      #row 2, col 1
        SizerF.Add(ScratchWrk)           #row 2, col 2
        SizerF.Add(labelMergeFile)       #row 3, col 1
        SizerF.Add(MergeFile)            #row 3, col 2

        SizerB = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        SizerB.Add(Run, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        SizerB.Add(ExitB, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)

        Sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        Sizer1.Add(SizerF, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        Sizer1.Add(SizerB, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        Sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer()
        Sizer2.Add(Output, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        SizerFinal = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        SizerFinal.Add(Sizer1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        SizerFinal.Add(Sizer2, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)


        self.SetSizerAndFit(SizerFinal)

    #--- START EVENT HANDLERS

    def OnChooseRoot(self, Event=None):
        # In this case we include a "New directory" button. 
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:",
                          style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE
                           #| wx.DD_DIR_MUST_EXIST
                           #| wx.DD_CHANGE_DIR
                           )

        # If the user selects OK, then we process the dialog's data.
        # This is done by getting the path data from the dialog - BEFORE
        # we destroy it. 
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            RootPath = dlg.GetPath()
            self.ChooseRoot.SetValue(RootPath)

        # Only destroy a dialog after you're done with it.
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnRun(self, Event=None):
        #First check if any of the boxes is empty
        pass

    def OnExit(self, Event=None):
        self.GetParent().Close()


    #--- END EVENT HANDLERS

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, title, size = (430,330),
                          style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        self.CreateStatusBar() 
        #------------- Setting up the menu
        filemenu = wx.Menu()
        filemenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Exit the program")
        #------------- Creating the menu
        menubar = wx.MenuBar()
        menubar.Append(filemenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)
        #---------- Setting menu event handlers
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, ID_EXIT, self.OnExit)                    
        #--- Add MainPanel
        self.Panel = MainPanel(self, -1)

        self.SetMaxSize(self.GetSize()) #Sets the Maximum size the window can have
        self.SetMinSize(self.GetSize()) #Sets the Minimum size the window can have
        #Centre on Screen
        self.CentreOnScreen()

        ###---- SHOW THE WINDOW
        self.Show(True)

    def OnExit(self,  event):
        self.Close(True) # Close the Frame
    #--- END EVENT HANDLERS ---------------------------------



if __name__=='__main__':

    try:
        app = wx.PySimpleApp()
        frame = MainWindow(None, -1, "IndexGenerator")
        app.MainLoop()
    finally:
        del app
```

Answer (score 3):

Read carefully advices that I have given you in your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186012/wxpython-setminsize-problem). Especially:

- use object properties for the widgets, so you do not loose track of them (`self.ChooseRoot =...`)
- use more desriptive widget names (`self.labelChooseRoot`)

Outside of the `__init__` method (aka constructor) you loose track of your widgets. You have to add them to your `MainPanel` object as attributes.

```
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        ...
        self.ChooseRoot = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        ...

    def OnChooseRoot(self, event=None):
        ...
        self.ChooseRoot.SetValue(RootPath)
        ...
```

I would also recommend some reading on OOP concepts. Maybe you can start from [here](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/ch13.html).

**Edit:**
You nearly got it working. The idea was OK, you just forgot a few places. I have updated your code to conform with my "standard", deleted some unnecessary copy/paste stuff and some other minor tweaks. Use some compare software and do a careful compare to see the changes if you like.

```
import wx 

ID_EXIT = 110

class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.buttonRun = wx.Button(self, label="Run")
        self.buttonRun.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnRun )
        self.buttonExit = wx.Button(self, label="Exit")
        self.buttonExit.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnExit)

        self.labelChooseRoot = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Root catalog: ") 
        self.labelScratchWrk = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Scratch workspace: ")
        self.labelMergeFile = wx.StaticText(self, label ="Merge file: ")

        self.textChooseRoot = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textChooseRoot.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnChooseRoot)
        self.textScratchWrk = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textMergeFile = wx.TextCtrl(self, size=(210, -1))
        self.textOutput = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)

        self.sizerF = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 5, 5)
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelChooseRoot)  #row 1, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textChooseRoot)   #row 1, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelScratchWrk)  #row 2, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textScratchWrk)   #row 2, col 2
        self.sizerF.Add(self.labelMergeFile)   #row 3, col 1
        self.sizerF.Add(self.textMergeFile)    #row 3, col 2

        self.sizerB = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonRun, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.sizerB.Add(self.buttonExit, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT|wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizer1 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerF, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 10)
        self.sizer1.Add(self.sizerB, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.sizer2 = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer2.Add(self.textOutput, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 5)

        self.sizerFinal = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer1, 0, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)
        self.sizerFinal.Add(self.sizer2, 1, wx.ALIGN_RIGHT | wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizerFinal)


    def OnChooseRoot(self, event):
        dlg = wx.DirDialog(self, "Choose a directory:", style=wx.DD_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            root_path = dlg.GetPath()
            self.textChooseRoot.SetValue(root_path)
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnRun(self, event):
        #First check if any of the boxes is empty
        pass

    def OnExit(self, event):
        self.GetParent().Close()


class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="IndexGenerator", size=(430, 330), 
                          style=((wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.NO_FULL_REPAINT_ON_RESIZE | 
                                  wx.STAY_ON_TOP) ^ wx.RESIZE_BORDER))
        self.CreateStatusBar() 

        self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()
        self.fileMenu.Append(ID_EXIT, "E&xit", "Exit the program")
        self.menuBar = wx.MenuBar()
        self.menuBar.Append(self.fileMenu, "&File")
        self.SetMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        wx.EVT_MENU(self, ID_EXIT, self.OnExit)                    

        self.Panel = MainPanel(self)

        self.CentreOnScreen()
        self.Show()

    def OnExit(self,  event):
        self.Close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Hello again. Ive tried this, but pytonw.exe freezes. Thats why I thought it was wrong. The main program is   `if __name__=='__main__':  
    
    try:  
        app = wx.PySimpleApp()  
        frame = MainWindow(None, -1, "IndexGenerator")  
        app.MainLoop()  
    finally:  
        del app`    Maybe this causes it? Should I add self to the sizer as well? Tried adding self to all but sizers and pytonw.exe still hangs.  Sorry about the layout, problems formatting the comment.

Comment: Please update your question above with whole runnable program.

Comment: I have updated your code. Read it carefully to get all the points.

Comment: Thanks alot Fenikso. See you did some changes regarding app and the MainWindow class. I'll check it out. =)